# Django psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth error but not connecting to postgresql database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I am using the following sqlite connection in my myapp/settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':testdb:',
        #I also tried 'NAME': 'testdb',
    },
}
```

in my manage.py file I am using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("myapp.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

On running ./manage.py migrate on the command line I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I tried removing psycopg2 and re-ran the migration and get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

I can't work out why django is trying to connect to a psql database where the only DATABSES configuration in the application is for sqlite3.

Could this be due to a dependency?

Comment: It's probably due to one of the dependencies. Do you mind sharing your entire `settings.py` file. I believe some where there, there is an import which is overriding your `DATABASES` variable

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaKornepati yes was dependency related, I edited the source code in a dep. to fix it. You can put your comment above and perhaps an explanation on why it must be a dependency if I am not using psql anywhere in my settings and I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django only uses `DATABASES` setting to generate migrations using a specific database driver. I believe somewhere, there is an import which is overriding your `DATABASES` setting. These are possible places to look for debugging in order of priority.

1. Any import into `settings.py` file after you set `DATABASES` variable which might override it.
2. if above is not the case, Some dependency must be overriding this setting manually. you might want to look into your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
3. If still not enough, you might need to look at any other dependency that you are using in your project which tries to interact with django.

Comment: Ok, what if you have nothing overriding it?

Comment: u mean if you are using postgres database? if yes you just need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

This might be helpful for you.

Comment: I get same error as before, I'm pretty sure the issue is dependency related. Will work though and post answer if I can solve it